# SQL CONCAT columns and adding return after each nonempty entry

Tags: mysql, sql, concatenation

I have a very specific question.
I have to build a SQL statement that builds a table where some columns are merged together. These columns shall be formatted with delimiters like '\n' or ' ' or ' - '. These delimiters shall be added only if the column before is not empty or null. This should prevent empty lines or unneeded delimiters.

Here is how I started:

```
SELECT
    any_table.table_id,
    CONCAT(any_table.text1, '\n', any_table.text2) AS text1_2,

FROM
    any_table

WHERE any_table.use = 'true'
```

This code concats text1 and text2 as a new column text1_2 and uses a line feed as delimiter. The missing part is that line feed shall just be added if any_table.text1 is not null or empty.

Is there an elegant way in doing this with SQL?

thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some databases support a very handy function called `concat_ws()` which does exactly what you want:

```
CONCAT_WS('\n', NULLIF(any_table.text1, ''), NULLIF(any_table.text2, '')) AS text1_2,
```

In standard SQL, you can do:

```
TRIM(LEADING '\n' FROM CONCAT( '\n', || NULLIF(any_table.text1, ''),
                               '\n' || NULLIF(any_table.text2, '')
                             )
    )
```

It is possible that your database supports neither of these constructs.

Comment: I don't think `concat()` is standard SQL

Comment: The first code works for me perfectly fine. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

if you'r under SQL SERVER you can use,

```
SELECT id, CONCAT(colonne1 + ' - ', colonne2) FROM "table"
```

if you'r under Oracle :  you shoul use `||` for concaténation like

```
SELECT id, CONCAT(colonne1 || ' - ', colonne2) FROM "table"
```